# How to properly process 3D Point Cloud data in python?

Tags: python, process, point-clouds, open3d, laspy

I am new to this forum, so this will be my first question ever (by having used the forum for several years now :D).

**What's my Problem:**
I am working in a Company now, where we want to automate processes like finding lowest and/or highest points/lines in classified 3d point cloud data (such as walls, roofs, ...). So I have a classified point cloud where I don't want to draw the lines myself of the lowest and highest points of walls or roofs or anythin, but figure out how python could do the job for me instead!

**What I'd like to know:**
To start, I'd like to know what is the best and proper way to process point cloud data using python? I came up with several ideas by simply google searching (such as laspy, open3d, ...) but I am very confused, which one might be the library I'd need for my mission or where I should really start to put effort in learning to deal with a certain package..

So, I am grateful for your answers and suggestions (maybe there exists a similar entry which I haven't found already?).

Thanks
Max

Comment: `open3d` seems to have a lot of features. Have you checked the [pointcloud](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud.html) page in the documentation and can it do everything you want?

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer - yes I think so too, maybe I should get started with open3d and eventually some more opinions pop up here as well. I started with laspy, but that seems to be quite restricted though..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the Open3D Tutorials found [here](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud.html#Point-cloud-distance).

There isn't one that does exactly what you're looking for, but pretty dam close (IMO).

I'm not interested in doing what you're doing, but if I was this is where I'd figure it out.